# Login Screen (Python)

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have limited understanding. When I execute my code it doesn't print anything out.

If anyone needs more details, please let me know:

```
def main():
    login()

def login():
    username="john"
    password="apple"
    print("Enter username:")
    answer1=input()
    print("Enter password:")
    answer2=input()
    if answer1==username and answer2==password:
        print("Welcome - Access Granted")
        menu()

def menu():
    print("************MAIN MENU**************")
```

Comment: You are not calling `main`. Add `main()` in the last line of the script.

Comment: Or better: `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined all your functions well, but you never call them. So you're telling the interpreter here is what every functions does but dont call them yet. This result is doing nothing.

Here is an example where I call main():

```
def main():
    login()

def login():
    username="john"
    password="apple"
    print("Enter username:")
    answer1=input()
    print("Enter password:")
    answer2=input()
    if answer1==username and answer2==password:
        print("Welcome - Access Granted")
        menu()

def menu():
    print("************MAIN MENU**************")

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was very useful!

Comment: @Jack123 No problem! Please accept the answer if it was helpful to you. it is a good pratice to accept helpful anwers in order to close questions. Welcome to SO!

Comment: And then you write another script that wants to import a function from here, and `main()` gets called.

Comment: I think the goal here was to show him why nothing was happening. Obviously, he is new and didn't know about functions call. If you want to proposed an alternative, post an answer with an entire new code.

Comment: Well there is plenty of shortcomings in the code you posted also... There is always a better a version. But from what the user wanted to understand, I think my answer was good enough.

Comment: I agree, just saying, why not make it right from the start.

Comment: For the same reason you didn't provide an answer based on oriented-object programming using polymorphism. _Just barely good enough_

Answer (score 2):

`a1` and `a2` outside functions are called variables. So variable `a1` will contain username and variable `a2` will contain password if the user type and enter the data.

Once the function `main` is being called, it will return function `login` which is now carrying the arguments `a1` and `a2`. Don't be confused, variables `a1` and `a2` are now arguments.

Once a function is being called, the data inside are arguments. Once we create a function, the data inside are parameters. The parameters `answer1` and `answer2` can only be use inside the function `login`.

Our purpose of storing data outside the function is that we can use them to another functions we created in the future. :)

```
def main():
    return login(a1,a2)

def login(answer1, answer2):
    username = "john"
    password = "apple"
    if answer1==username and answer2==password:
        print("Welcome - Access Granted.")
        menu()
    else:
        pass

def menu():
    print("***MAIN MENU***")


print("Enter username:")
a1 = input()

print("Enter password:")
a2 = input()

main()
```

Comment: the user asking the question is obviously new. You're answer doesn"t give any feedback on why he should use your code.

Comment: "try this" is rarely good enough. Except for the cases where advanced python users are directly asking for working code.

Comment: Okay, well for the OP I'm just giving him a new ideal solution relating to his problem. I love sharing new ideas :)

Comment: It is a really good thing to do that, maybe you could update your answer to give feedback on why you propose this solution ?

Comment: I hope my explanations are useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is safer, because you can execute the file as well as importing it without executing the `main()`. It is the standard way of creating an executable script.

```
def main():
    login()

def login():
    username="john"
    password="apple"
    print("Enter username:")
    answer1=input()
    print("Enter password:")
    answer2=input()
    if answer1==username and answer2==password:
        print("Welcome - Access Granted")
        menu()

def menu():
    print("************MAIN MENU**************")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Read more about it there: [what-does-if-name-main-do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)